# Understanding references in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to understand the tutorial on references in Perl

```
perldoc perlreftut
```

So far with the code below, I'm initializing an empty hash with

```
my %table
```

Here is the whole program

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 
use strict;

my %table;

while (<DATA>) {
chomp;
my ($city, $country) = split /, /;
#$table{$country} = [] unless exists $table{$country};
push @{$table{$country}}, $city;

print @{$table{$country}};
}



__DATA__
Chicago, USA
Frankfurt, Germany
Berlin, Germany
Washington, USA
Helsinki, Finland
New York, USA
```

Can somebody explain to me the line below because I'm confused since I see a reference (I think) here but it was initialized as a hash with %table.

```
push @{$table{$country}}, $city;
```

Comment: So, on the first iterate, it will look like this:
`%table = ( 'USA' => [ 'Chicago' ] )`; `$city` is 'Chicago' which be pushed into a reference `$table{$country}` and where `@{ $table{$country} }`  is the array reference; correct me if I am wrong the autovivification is the magic that puts in the `%table`?

Comment: @BioRod, After the first iteration, it will indeed look like `%table = ( 'USA' => [ 'Chicago' ] );`. Added this to my answer. /// `$table{$country}` is the array reference. `@{ $table{$country} }` is the array. /// Autovivification is what creates the reference and the array and puts the reference in `$table{$country}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are [*declaring*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_(computer_programming)) the hash `%table`. The *declaration* is when you tell Perl that there is a lexically scoped variable. *Initialization* is when you assign a value to a variable the first time. You did not [*initialize*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)) it, so Perl puts a default value. Because it's a hash, it starts out with an empty list `()`, which amounts to *false*.

You do have a dereference operator in this line.

```
push @{$table{$country}}, $city;
```

It says take the value `$table{$country}` as an array reference, dereference it, and then push `$city` into that array. There is a feature called [auto-vivification](http://perlmaven.com/autovivification) that automatically creates the necessary array ref before the value is pushed.

So after the first round over the input, you now have this data structure:

```
%table = ( 'USA' => [ 'Chicago' ] )
```

`%table` is a hash, but the key `USA` inside that hash holds an array reference.

To create multi-level data structures in Perl, you need reference. But the first level does not need to be a reference. It can be a hash or an array.

Comment: In Perl declaring a lexical variable using `my` initializes it too. Scalars are initialized to undef, and hashes and arrays are initialized to empty.

Comment: The link to auto-vivification helped alot.

Answer (score 8):

`%table` is a hash,
`$table{$country}` is a reference to an array, and
`@{ $table{$country} }` is the referenced array.

This data structure is a "hash of references to arrays", though it is called "hash of array" for short, and it's abbreviated "HoA".

---

But where do the reference and the array come from? They are autovivified, meaning that Perl created them for you when you treated `$table{$country}` as a reference to an array.

In other words,

```
push @{ $table{$country} }, $city
```

is short for

```
push @{ $table{$country} //= [] }, $city
```

So, after the first `push`, you'll go from having an empty hash to having

```
%table = ( 'USA' => [ 'Chicago' ] );
```

---

Docs:

- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)

Comment: `push @{ $table{$country} //= [] }, $city` `timtowtdi` or better `tamswtdi` `There are many shorter ways to do it.`